# $_SESSION not staying set after upgrade from PHP 5.4 to 7.1

Tags: php, session

I have been avoiding upgrading to 7. whatever since I knew one site gets along with it and others do not. The one that works is not my script so.....it must be me!

I get this error :

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/php_sessions/sess_o0o21b23hv37lhr2gf0e7hgeum9fiqqd, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in ........... on line 2

I created and uploaded the simplest test file possible:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[test]='Working';
var_dump($_COOKIE);
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Then I erased the `$_SESSION[test]='Working';` line and uploaded this:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_COOKIE);
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

So the `$_SESSION` returns empty. The session id stays the same each reload and if I start a fresh browser session with a new id, same issue. I downgraded all the way back to 5.6 with the same results. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this dir exist? `/var/php_sessions/`

Comment: looks like the folder on which is trying to read session data does not exists or cannot write files in int since error message is saying "open (path) failed no such file or directory..." please try to check if this path is correct

Comment: If you're upgrading from 5.x to 7.x I would **highly** recommend auditing your `php.ini` and make sure you've got your config set correctly. A lot of things changed and you might want to make sure you're up to date

Comment: I never changed anything in php.ini except for the file upload maximum so I assumed the defaults were similar. Also, how would I get the root of /var/php_sessions/ be so I can check? Also, how do I highlight words in the comments?

Comment: I looked up my old path and it was  4;/h.....s/phpsessions and I never set it up. I don't understand the structure of this path so I don't want to alter it to match the old path. What is going on with the "4;" part?

Comment: I did some googling and learned what the 4; means and got it going. The file path had been different. Thanks!